# How to filter specific values in a scope, and hide if there is a non desired type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations

Example: I have 2 budgets, each one of them `has_many budget_invoices`, with different types each...

```
Budget.first.budget_invoices.map{|x| x.type}
["BudgetInvoiceByWorkshopInput"]

Budget.last.budget_invoices.map{|x| x.type}
["BudgetInvoiceByInsurerInput", "BudgetInvoiceByWorkshopOutput"]
```

In my scope I want to filter budgets that only have `budget_invoices` of the **workshop/insurer** type.

**ByWorkshop:**

```
includes(:budget => :budget_invoices).where('budget_invoices.type IN (?) AND budget_invoices.budget_id = budgets.id', ["BudgetInvoiceByWorkshopInput", "BudgetInvoiceByWorkshopOutput"])
```

**ByInsurer:**

```
includes(:budget => :budget_invoices).where('budget_invoices.type IN (?) AND budget_invoices.budget_id = budgets.id', ["BudgetInvoiceByInsurerInput", "BudgetInvoiceByInsurerOutput"])
```

When I use the "ByWorkshop" scope the result I get is the first and the last Budget, which is correct. But for some reason when I use the "ByWorkshop" scope, together with another scope; **to not** filter Budgets that has budget_invoices of the insurer type...

```
includes(:budget => :budget_invoices).where('budget_invoices.type NOT IN (?) AND budget_invoices.budget_id = budgets.id',["BudgetInvoiceByInsurerInput", "BudgetInvoiceByInsurerOutput"])
```

...It still brings me the first and last budget, which is incorrect, it should've bring me only the first budget since the last one contains a value that I don't want...

Comment: I'd like to suggest using rails `not` operator `includes(:budget => :budget_invoices).where.not('budget_invoices.type IN (?) AND budget_invoices.budget_id = budgets.id', ["BudgetInvoiceByWorkshopInput", "BudgetInvoiceByWorkshopOutput"])
`? I guess this would be a 'rails way' of doing a not query

Comment: That didnt work, and i dont think that NOT IN would be the problem.